# Why is my code for checking for an internet connection failing?

Tags: command-line, ping

I am trying to edit a script so that it will check for an internet connection before executing the rest of its commands, but the problem is that no matter what I try the result (online or not) the answer is always 0 I have provided the code that I came up with below in hopes that someone could look at it and give some ideas on how to solve my plight. I have tried multiple ways with all the same result. I can provide more of the code or my computer information if needed thanks.

```
[root@MercadesBendz MyWirelessCard]# TEST=$(ping -c 1 74.125.21.147) [
$TEST >/dev/null 2>&1 ] && echo 1 || echo 0

0
```

Comment: What OS? Linux?

Comment: Yes: Linux 4.4.8-300.fc23.x86_64  GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the result of pinc-c 1 74.125.21.147 is not a number - its the string with the result - and you are then checking if its null or not - but its never null, because it will report back regardless of a failure.

I played arround, and modified it slightly - its less elegant, but works for me:

```
 TEST=$(ping -c 1 74.125.21.14|wc -l);  [ $TEST -gt 5 2>&1 ] && echo 1 || echo 0
```

The idea here is that the test now counts the number of lines.  5 Lines of results indicates a failure, 6 or more indicates a pass.   You can make this more robust by increasing the number of pings and the number of lines you count, which can account for some level of packet loss as well.

There are other alternatives - for example, instead of counting the number of lines, you can do something like | tail -2 | head -1 | cut -f4 to get the number of packets received.

Comment: Cool thanks for the advice. I tried the revised code and it did indeed work.
Yeah I am not looking for elegant because it is going into a personal script for me. :) :)

Comment: Hey since this works, it it possible to exit the script if there is no internet available? I tried a method but it kept exiting my script even if I had internet connection?
`#Check internet availablity
TEST=$(ping -c 1 74.125.21.14|wc -l)
[ $TEST -gt 5 2>&1 ] || exit`

Comment: Rather then use [ $TEST...   why not convert it into an if [ $TEST -gt 5 ] with a then and else statement ?  Alternatively, split the script into 2 parts, and call a second script rather then the echo

Comment: Um well I tried that too, I believe, in another script:
`#Check internet availablity
TEST=$(ping -c 1 74.125.21.14|wc -l)
if [ $TEST -gt 5 2>&1 ]
then
    sudo dnf install gcc kernel-devel binutils cpp glibc-devel glibc-headers isl kernel kernel-headers libmpc
else
    echo "No Internet Connection Available! Installing RPMs manuely."
    arr=(*.rpm)
    for (( i=0; i<${#arr[@]}; i++ ));
    do
        echo " ${arr[$i]} "
        dnf -y install ${arr[$i]}
    done
#exit is commented out because it always closed my script
#exit
fi;`

Comment: Please post this as another question (and comment with the link) so I can help further, its to difficult without formatting, and is really a different problem.  Also, Can you define script - Are you trying to run the whole thing from the command line, or whaat do you mean by )exit is commented out because it always closed my script)

Comment: Okay I will, but for some reason it is working properly now... I don't know why. I will be sure to do that if the problem happens again and isn't making a lair out of me. So please forgive me as I am new to scripting, but it is working proper now and I cross my fingers that it stays that way.